# Why can't we calculate job execution time in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, job-scheduling

My question is related to Straggler problem. In sort, it's an algorithm and we can know its complexity and calculate the running time when executed on a constant set of data.

Why can't we acquire job execution time in Hadoop ?

If we can acquire the job execution time or task execution time, we can know the straggler tasks quickly without needing algorithms to know which task is Straggler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not estimate how much time a job will take before running that job.
After running your mapreduce job, you can take an estimation of the time taken.
Mapreduce always depends on your cluster capacity – RAM size, CPU Cores and network band width – and how many Reducers you set for the task.

You can only make assumptions based on your RAM size divided by the input split.

Comment: thanks so much, now I know why we can't calculate the time accurately because of it depends on many things like cluster capacity and network bandwidth and those can changes during the execution

Answer (score 2):

The job execution time or the task execution time will be available in the job tracker web UI.Hope that is what you are looking for.the web UI will be availlable in 50030 port of your job tracker.If its a Yarn based setup the url would be http://:8088

Comment: so if the task execution time is available before I run task , when does straggler problem happen?  and also how do hadoop know the execution time of a task before running it?

Comment: Only realtime task execution time will be available.Only after running the task,the time is displayed.Not upfront.