# Measuring Execution Time in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I would like to discuss the total resource usage of my MapReduce jobs and wonder how I could do this. Hadoop provides the CPU millis metric for jobs, but I wonder if this is a good idea.

As an alternative, I could add up different times: Map time, Sort time, Merge time and Reduce time, but this gives a number that is different from the total CPU time I mentioned above. I do not know why this is the case, I suspect that it is caused by "IO-wait" time, i.e., waiting for resources (such as disk) to become available.

Finally, in papers, I often find references to the "execution time". Is this the total time (sum of all resource usage), or is this the elapsed time (end-start)?

This leads to the following two questions:

1. what is the definition of execution time? is this "elapsed time", or is this total time?
2. how can I best represent the resource usage in Hadoop, is CPU millis adequate?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26876261/why-cant-we-calculate-job-execution-time-in-hadoop And did you check the ref? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerRest.html

Comment: @gsamaras that is about obtaining it before running, no?

Comment: Yes the first link was not a good option, but I think the second is.

Comment: @gsamaras this does not provide any more info on execution time, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but maybe you are right. I will upvote. "but this gives different numbers". From what? Expand please.

Comment: If you have millisecond execution time, Hadoop is way too much of an overhead for the jobs you are running

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't have this kind of jobs, Hadoop offers millisecond counters